# Symfony : JMS Job queue Bundle Job Listener

Tags: symfony, jobs, event-listener, jmsjobqueuebundle

Is it possible to set up an Event Listener on Job Status Change from JMS-Job-Queue-Bundle in Symfony? 
I am trying to update my database when a job failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an Event dispatcher from Symfony. You can get it from container by name `event_dispatcher`:

```
$dispatcher = $container->get('event_dispatcher');
```

Then you can register your event listener as a closure:

```
use JMS\JobQueueBundle\Event\StateChangeEvent;
use JMS\JobQueueBundle\Entity\Job;

$dispatcher->addListener('jms_job_queue.job_state_change', function (StateChangeEvent $event) {
    if ($event->getNewState() == Job::STATE_FAILED) {
        $job = $event->getJob();
        // do what you need here
    }
});
```

Also you can create separate class for this Event listener and use it like this:

```
$listener = new YourListener();
$dispatcher->addListener('jms_job_queue.job_state_change', array($listener, 'onStateChange'));
```

And your `YourListener` class must look like this:

```
use JMS\JobQueueBundle\Event\StateChangeEvent;
use JMS\JobQueueBundle\Entity\Job;

class YourListener
{
    // ...

    public function onStateChange(StateChangeEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->getNewState() == Job::STATE_FAILED) {
            $job = $event->getJob();
            // do what you need here
        }
    }
}
```

Also if you have Symfony project you can use more convenient way. Just define your `YourListener` class in `services.yml` and tag it with tag `kernel.event_listener`:

```
your_listener:
    class:      AppBundle\EventListener\YourListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: jms_job_queue.job_state_change, method: onStateChange }
```

Comment: Thank you, the main problem was that I couldn't find job event names.

Comment: You just forgot in your example the suscriber in services.yml in that case that would be:
    my_bundle.job_status_change:
        class: MyBundle\EventListener\YourListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: jms_job_queue.job_state_change, method: onStateChange }

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just forgot that you use Symfony. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: I added info about injecting listener through DIC.